# Htmx hx-indicator with multiple elements on page

Tags: html, bootstrap-5, codeigniter-4, htmx

I'm showing a loading spinner on my page when triggering a htmx-request like so:

```html
<div class="col-4 px-4dot5 py-3 bg-secondary-light">
    <label for="stellenangebotLink" class="form-label fs-5">Link</label>
    <div id="linkHelpBlock">E-Mail-Adresse oder Website-URL</div>
    <?= $this->include('components/_htmx_spinner') ?>
    <input
        hx-post="/medien/personal-kampagne/stellenangebot-modal/link"
        hx-trigger="keyup changed delay:300ms"
        hx-include="#stellenangebot_id"
        hx-target="#stellenangebotLinkWrapper"
        hx-indicator=".htmx-indicator"
        name="link"
        id="stellenangebotLink"
        class="form-control"
        aria-describedby="linkHelpBlock">
</div>
```

Spinner code:

```html
<div id="spinner" class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm mx-2 htmx-indicator" role="status">
  <span class="visually-hidden">Loading...</span>
</div>
```

The problem is that i have multiple such elements on my page and i only want to show the closest spinner. Furthermore i want to reuse that spinner-fragment on other elements (no sequential Ids).

The [hx-indicator page](https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-indicator/) says:

> The value of this attribute is a CSS query selector of the element or elements to apply the class to, or the keyword closest, followed by a CSS selector, which will find the closest ancestor element or itself, that matches the given CSS selector (e.g. closest tr);

But what is such a CSS selector? `closest .htmx-indicator` gives a javascript-error (`htmx.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'htmx-internal-data')`). `closest div` would be too broad.

So my question is: How can i select the closest spinner-fragment with `hx-indicator`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like they "translate" `closest .htmx-indicator` into the method call `.closest('.htmx-indicator')` - but that alone won't help you here, to actually target the `.htmx-indicator` element. `.closest()` checks the element itself and all its ancestors for a match to the selector - but your `.htmx-indicator` is not an ancestor of the input element, so it won't be found (and that then in turn explains the JS error you got.)

You *would* need to traverse downwards in the DOM tree again to actually find that spinner element, after you found a common ancestor of both, something like `.closest('div').querySelector('.htmx-indicator')` - but it doesn't look they provide any "syntax" for that.

> `closest div` would be too broad

Why? According to their documentation, whatever element you actually target, will get the `htmx-request` class added to it; and the stylesheet should already come with

```
.htmx-request .htmx-indicator{
    opacity:1
}
.htmx-request.htmx-indicator{
    opacity:1
}
```

So whether you manage to get the `.htmx-indicator` element itself getting the class `htmx-request` applied to it, or whether it gets set on the outermost `div` in your given example code, should not really matter - it should apply the opacity value to `.htmx-indicator` either way ...?

(And that ID there on `<div id="spinner"` should go, if you include that same code in multiple places on one page.)

Comment: I was under the impression that js's `closest()` would find sibling elements. What i ended up doing is using `hx-indicator="previous .htmx-indicator"` which selects my spinner element if it comes before the triggering element in the same hierarchy.

Comment: About that last 2 paragraph: That seems logical, guess i just messed that up..